# Spritekit keep iPhone music while gaming

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer

to play sound and music I use both  `SKAction.playSoundFileNamed`
 and `AVAudioPlayer`.

If I'm playing a music in my iPhone and I'll open my game, my game stops the music. If I open another game, the music doesn't stop.

**Anyone know how to still the music playing?**

my sound manager class is:

```
class SoundManager {

    static let sharedInstance = SoundManager()

    /// Short Incidental Sound SKAction
    let coin = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("coin.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
    let newLevel = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("newLevel.wav", waitForCompletion: true)
    let blup = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("singleWater.wav", waitForCompletion: true)

    let pop = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("estrazionePop" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true)
    let pip = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("estrazionePip" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true)
    let split = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("split" + ".mp3", waitForCompletion: true)
    let fire = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("fire" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true)
    let stoneStop     = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("stoneStop" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true)

    let small = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("BvS-Exp-Small" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true)
    let medium = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("BvS-Exp-Medium" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true)
    let big = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("BvS-Exp-Big" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true)

    let smallBoss = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("BvS-Exp-Boss-Small" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true)
    let mediumBoss = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("BvS-Exp-Boss-Medium" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true)
    let bigBoss = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("BvS-Exp-Boss-Big" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true)

    let bombInizio = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("BombInizio" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true)
    let bombScintilla:SKAudio = SKAudio(fileName: "BombScintilla" + ".wav", numberOfLoops: -1)
    let bombBoom = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("BombBoom" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true)

    let spiderSvamp = [
        SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Fhh0" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true),
        //SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Fhh1" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true), non mi piacciono
        //SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Fhh2" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true),
        SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Fhh3" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true),
        SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Fhh4" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true),
        SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Fhh5" + ".wav", waitForCompletion: true)
    ]

    ///Suoni lunghi
    var gameover: SKAudio = SKAudio(fileName: "gameover" + ".mp3", numberOfLoops: 0)
}
```

and

```
class SKAudio {
    var audio: AVAudioPlayer!
    var url: URL?

    fileprivate var numberOfLoops:Int!

    ///-1 infinite, 0 = once
    init(fileName: String, numberOfLoops:Int? = -1) {
        url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: nil)
        self.numberOfLoops = numberOfLoops
    }

    func playSound() {
        if (url == nil) {
            print("Could not find the file \(audio)")
        }

        do {
            audio = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!, fileTypeHint: nil)

        }
        catch let error as NSError { print(error.debugDescription)

        }
        if audio == nil {
            print("Could not create audio player")
        }
        else {
            audio.prepareToPlay()
            audio.numberOfLoops = numberOfLoops
            audio.play()
        }
    }

    func pause() {
        if let player = audio {
            if player.isPlaying {
                player.pause()
            }
        }
    }

    func resume() {
        if let player = audio {
            if !player.isPlaying {
                player.play()
            }
        }
    }
    func stop() {
        if let player = audio {
            if player.isPlaying {
                player.stop()
            }
        }
    }
    func isPlaying() -> Bool {
        if let player = audio {
            return player.isPlaying
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
    func increaseVolume(value:Float) {
        if let player = audio {
            if player.isPlaying {
                if player.volume != 1.0 {
                    let incrrease = min(value, 1.0)
                    player.volume += incrrease
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func decreaseVolume(value:Float) {
        if let player = audio {
            if player.isPlaying {
                if player.volume != 0.0 {
                    let decr = max(value, 0.0)
                    player.volume -= decr
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func setVolume(value:Float) {
        if let player = audio {
            var val = max(value, 0.0)
            val = min(value, 1.0)
            player.volume = val
        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the situation, you wanna be able to listen to music in the music app for example and play your game at the same time, right?

I'm not very familiar with spriteKit, but for a normal app you could use [AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryambient) so your app won't stop other sounds.

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
```